# Spark: How to group the dataframe in columns

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I have this dataframe "df":

| Country | customer | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| England | John | 4 |
| France | Sally | 3 |
| England | John | 2 |
| France | Sally | 1 |

I would like to create a new df called "out", where I group the "Country" column in rows and the "customer" one in columns. The cells shouls show the sum:

| Country | John | Sally |
| --- | --- | --- |
| England | 6 | 0 |
| France | 0 | 4 |

I know how to groupby the rows with:

```
out = df.groupby.("Country").agg(sum("total"))
```

But I don't know how to groupby the "customer" column in the columns (keeping the first column named as "Country".

Thanks!

Comment: use pivot. i'll leave the guide in the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you want to pivot your data
imagin if you have this data set:

```
+-------+------+-------+
|Product|Amount|Country|
+-------+------+-------+
| Banana|  1000|    USA|
|Carrots|  1500|    USA|
|  Beans|  1600|    USA|
| Orange|  2000|    USA|
| Orange|  2000|    USA|
| Banana|   400|  China|
|Carrots|  1200|  China|
|  Beans|  1500|  China|
| Orange|  4000|  China|
| Banana|  2000| Canada|
|Carrots|  2000| Canada|
|  Beans|  2000| Mexico|
+-------+-----+-------+
```

and would like to pivot it like this:

```
+-------+------+-----+------+----+
|Product|Canada|China|Mexico| USA|
+-------+------+-----+------+----+
| Orange|  null| 4000|  null|4000|
|  Beans|  null| 1500|  2000|1600|
| Banana|  2000|  400|  null|1000|
|Carrots|  2000| 1200|  null|1500|
```

which i think it's the way you want it to be, then you need to run your code like this:

```
val pivotDF = df.groupBy("Product").pivot("Country").sum("Amount")
pivotDF.show()
```

For reference: [Click Here](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/how-to-pivot-table-and-unpivot-a-spark-dataframe/)